# Recovering lm() results from a data.table groupby models

Tags: r, data.table

I need to analyse the output of a series of lm() output from a data.table group_by regressions:

```
library(data.table)
x <- c(1:5,66:70,101:110) 
y <- 31:50
g <- c( 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1          
       ,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)

dt <- data.table(x,y,g)
mod <- dt[ , .(model = .(lm(x~y, .SD)))
           , by = g]
```

`mod` has the correct models for each group `g`. Now I want to create a column with the residuals vector for each group `g`:

```
mod[, resi := residuals(model)
    , by = g]
```

It seems to run correctly, but the nem column `resi` was not created:

```
> mod
       g    model
   <num>   <list>
1:     1 <lm[12]>
2:     2 <lm[12]>
```

Why does this not work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are applying residuals() to `list(model)` instead of directly to the model object.

```
mod[, resi := .(list(residuals(model[[1]])))
    , by = g]

# Or 

mod[, resi := lapply(model, residuals)]

#        g    model                                                                                    resi
#    <num>   <list>                                                                                  <list>
# 1:     1 <lm[12]>                    10.909091,  1.818182, -7.272727,-16.363636,-25.454545, 25.454545,...
# 2:     2 <lm[12]> -1.471465e-14, 6.482041e-15, 5.472051e-15, 4.101520e-15, 2.842011e-15, 1.526991e-15,...
```

Comment: Can yo explain in the first version why we have to wrap this in two lists? `.(list(residuals(model[[1]])))`

Comment: @FabioCorrea the second version works perfectly.

Comment: @Ludwig I suggest just try `mod[, .(residuals(model[[1]])) , by = g]` and see what happens.

Comment: That settles it, thank you @s_baldur